# Stochastic processes and Markov chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stopping-times

In my course i have defined stopping times, first passage times and hitting times, where the first passage time is $T_{i,j} = \inf( n>0 : X _n=j)$ and $H_i=\inf(n\geq0 : X_n=i)$. stopping times are those that only look into the history/ past of the Markov chains to see if the event has happened. However, we had also defined excursion times, which was $S_i^r= T_i^r-T_i^{r-1}$, which we deduced is not a stopping time. I don't understand why this is the case since $S_i^r$ only looks into the past to see if the events have happened, and by the SMP, even though both $T_i^r-T_i^{r-1}$ are random stopping times, we can condition on them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, are you asking why we can condition on random stopping times? There're still (time) bounds you can condition on the stopping times right? Like the sixth time the event has happened has to be after the fifth time.